# Carrousel para cada card con Swiper no funciona al aplicar un filtro en la pagina

Tags: javascript, swiper

Estoy con un problema y no se me ocurre una solucion. Estoy haciendo una pagina y quiero que las cards tengan un carrousel para mostrar 3 fotos y el mismo funciona al entrar a la pagina. El problema esta al aplicar filtros de busqueda (En mi caso son "Alquiler", "Venta", "Ver propiedades destacadas"), cuando aplico los mismos, solo aparece la primera imagen y desaparece el carrousel.
Estoy usando HTML5, JS, Swiper y CSS.
Les dejo el link a la pagina asi ven a lo que me refiero:
https://eduardofernandezpropiedades.vercel.app/.
Adjunto el codigo aqui debajo. Si alguien puede darme una mano estaria muy agradecido.

```
    const botonAlquiler = document.getElementById('botonAlquiler');
    const botonVenta = document.getElementById('botonVenta');
    const botonQuitarFiltros = document.getElementById('botonQuitarFiltros'); 
    const propertiesCards = document.querySelector('.properties');
    const displayProperties = (tipoFiltro) => {
        propertiesCards.innerHTML = '';
    
        properties.forEach((property) => {
            if ( tipoFiltro === 'todos' || property.tipo === tipoFiltro) {
                const div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="propertyCard">        
                        <div class="swiper swiper-hero swiper-properties">
                            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <!-- Slides -->
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="${property.imagen}" alt="" class='propertyImg'></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="${property.imagen2}" alt="" class='propertyImg'></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="${property.imagen3}" alt="" class='propertyImg'></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- If we need pagination -->
                                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>              
                        </div> 
                        <a href=${property.linkPropiedad} class='aProperty'target="_blank">
                            <h2>${property.titulo}</h2>
                            <p>${property.direccion}</p>
                            <p class='propertyDescription'>${property.descripcion}</p>
                            <p>${property.precio}</p>
                        </a>                
                        <a href=${property.linkPropiedad} class="verProp" target="_blank">Ver propiedad</a>
    
                    </div>`;
                propertiesCards.appendChild(div);
            }
        });
    };
    
    
    botonAlquiler.addEventListener('click', () => {
        displayProperties('alquiler');
    });

botonVenta.addEventListener('click', () => {
    displayProperties('venta');
});

botonQuitarFiltros.addEventListener('click', () => {
    displayProperties('todos'); // Mostrar todas las propiedades
});

displayProperties('todos');



const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-hero', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    autoplay:{
        delay:3000,
    },
  
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
},);
```

Comment: Estas usando alguna librería? si es así menciónala en la pregunta, además agrega el HTML y el CSS

Comment: sisi, la libreria es Swiper y el html que use para las cards esta ahi en el codigo, lo puse con js para que se renderice dinamicamente.

Comment: Me refiero a los elementos que seleccionas con botonAlquiler, botonVentas, etc. lo que tienes en index.html. Además el arreglo 'properties' no se encuentra

Comment: el array properties esta en un archivo (data.js).
ahi pongo el resto del codigo.

Comment: <section id="Properties">           
            <h2 class="propertiesTitleSection">Propiedades destacadas</h2>
            <div class="filterList">
                <button id="botonQuitarFiltros" class="filterBtnReset">Todas las propiedades destacadas</button>
                <button id="botonAlquiler" class="filterBtn">Alquiler</button>
                <button id="botonVenta" class="filterBtn">Venta</button>
            </div> 
            <div class="properties"></div></section>

Comment: Hola hermano, te comento que lo pude solucionar, creo que esta medio atado con alambre pero funciona. Muchas gracias por coparte y tratar de darme una mano. que tengas un buen fin de semana!. saludos!.